# Python: Choose 1 out of 2 random variables

Tags: python

I'm making a python game and I need random points to be generated. Basically, I want it to chose 2 random coordanates, and then chose 1 out of those 2. Although, The code below gives me "ValueError: empty range for randrange() (262, -201, -463)"

```
import random

xx1 = random.randrange(200,300)
xx2 = random.randrange(-300, -200)
yy1 = random.randrange(200, 300)
yy2 = random.randrange(-300, -200)
x = random.randint(xx1, xx2)
y = random.randint(yy1, yy2)
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't generate that error.  All the `randrange` calls are valid.  FYI, use `random.choice()` to pick one of a list of choices, e.g. `random.choice([xx1,xx2])`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x = random.randint(xx2, xx1)

y = random.randint(yy2, yy1)
```

The start value has to be lower than the stop value.

[Example on usage](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_randint.asp)

Comment: I think it's not needed xx2 and yy2 are negative while xx1 and yy1 are positive.

Answer (score 0):

Range normally starts from lower value to higher value. In your code `random.randint(xx1, xx2)` you're passing the opposite (Higher to lower) direction. Hence it shows `ValueError: empty range for randrange()`.

See more details about randrange [click here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Correction:

```
import random

xx1 = random.randrange(200,300)
xx2 = random.randrange(-300, -200)
yy1 = random.randrange(200, 300)
yy2 = random.randrange(-300, -200)
x = random.randint(xx2, xx1)
y = random.randint(yy2, yy1)
```

EDIT: Further if you want to pass value from higher to lower, you should add a step into the function like `range(start, stop, step)`. And Return a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`. Then it will work fine.